# unwanted object property changed when changing another object property c#

Tags: c#, object, properties, copy, instance

from what i understand in other posts i know that my objects use same place in memory but how to separate these objects?
i tried to use `new` but it didn't work or i didn't used it correctly.

**Note** that i didnt paste setter and getter here.

```
class Supermarket
{
    List<Product> _products = new List<Product>{ };
    List<Customer> _customers = new List<Customer>{ };
}

class Customer
{
    List<Product> _purchased= new List<Product>{ };
}
class Product
{
    string _id;
    string _name;
    DateTime _expireDate;
    int _cost;
    int _count;
}
```

i add one **Product** in one Method.

```
Product product = new Product(...);
supermarket.Products.Add(product);
```

and in another method i want to copy the **Product** from `Supermarket.Products`
 to `Supermarket.Customers.Purchased`. so i want a copy but i cant get it.

here i want to make **Copy** but it does not work.

```
Product product = supermarket.Products[productIndex];
supermarket.Customers[customerIndex].Purchased.Add(product);
```

now the problem is when i change **Product** properties in **Customer** class , **Product** properties inside **Supermarket** will change too.
for example

```
supermarket.Customers[customerIndex].Purchased.Last().Count = ...
//now the Product supermarket.Products[productIndex] will change too witch is unwanted
```

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects

Comment: i dont know what is clone. im really new in c# and object oriental language ... can you tell me what should i write in simple way? @CuongLe

Comment: how your Product class looks like?

Comment: here i updated my post. i didnt paste all code. product have setter and getter and one constructor as usuall. @CuongLe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it is not working is because you are doing *shallow copy* by just  adding *the pointer* of product object into the list, not all properties. So if you change one, another will be affected accordingly.

You can use deep copy following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects), but this way you have to mark your class as `[Serializable]`. The simplest way which I think is to use Json serializer:

```
public static class CloneHelper 
{
    public static T Clone<T>(T source)
    {
        var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(source);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(serialized);
    }
}

var copyProduct = CloneHelper.Clone<Product>(product);
```

Or simply, you can manage by yourself as the below code, then it works:

```
Product product = supermarket.Products[productIndex];

Product copyProduct = new Product() {
    Id = product.Id,
    Name = product.Name,
    ExpireDate = product.ExpireDate,
    Cost = product.Cost,
    Count = product.Count   
};

supermarket.Customers[customerIndex].Purchased.Add(copyProduct);
```

Comment: No shallow copy happening here. He is just passing the object reference.